# MySQL MATCH AGAINST not giving result

Tags: mysql, match-against

I have made a MySQL statement with a MATCH AGAINST. I'm not used to use this function, but it looks really easy.

But when I use this query:

```
SELECT productnaam, 
       productomschrijving, 
       MATCH (productnaam, productomschrijving) AGAINST('Kop van Jut'), 
       MATCH (productnaam, productomschrijving) AGAINST('Springkussen')
FROM product
WHERE product.productid in (508, 578)
```

I get these output:
[image]

I really don't understand why I don't get a value greater than zero for 'Kop van Jut'. I've also tried to use double quotes, a plus sign and so on. Nothing works.

Can somebody tell me what I do wrong?

Comment: Because you're matching `MATCH (productomschrijving, productomschrijving) AGAINST('Kop van Jut'),` instead of `MATCH (productnaam, productomschrijving) AGAINST('Kop van Jut'),`

Comment: No, sorry. That's my mistake; I've tried many things. But also:

SELECT productnaam, productomschrijving, 
MATCH (productnaam, productomschrijving) AGAINST('+"Kop van Jut"'), 
MATCH (productnaam, productomschrijving) AGAINST('+"Springkussen"')
FROM product 
WHERE 
product.productid in (508, 578)

Gives the same results.

Comment: Is your table MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: @Nick it is MyISAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `'Kop van Jut'` returns a 0 result is that the words in your search string are too short. For MyISAM tables, the minimum word length that is considered in a full-text search is 4 characters. From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html):

> - Some words are ignored in full-text searches:
>
>   Any word that is too short is ignored. The default minimum length of words that are found by full-text searches is three characters for
>     InnoDB search indexes, or four characters for MyISAM.

If you can set system variables, you can adjust the value of [`ft_min_word_len`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) down to 3 to make your match work on that particular search string.

Comment: That's the problem. Never knew this. Thank you very much!